# How to resolve error: Missing the environment variable 'TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, twitter, discord

I am a beginnner in programming so least expect I will encounter any error ahead. This day, coded some Node.js application to post Twitter Feeds to Discord but fail to do so.

I can't figure out why I am seeing this error although I've already supplied the .env file with necessary data. Already run the necessary dependencies likes, **npm install gm**, **npm i dotenv**. Code is below.

```html
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const commandExistsSync = require('command-exists').sync;
const logger = require('./bin/logger');
const { version } = require('./package.json');

logger.info(`Starting the twitter-to-discord application v${version}`);

// Extract all the env variables we will be using
const {
  TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEYS,
  TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
  TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
  TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
  MONGO_URI,
  DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN,
  DISCORD_CMD_PREFIX,
  DISCORD_BOT_OWNER_ID,
  TEMP,
} = process.env;

// Exit if the env variable was not set or passed. None can be empty
function envTest(value, name) {
  logger.debug(`${name}=${value}`);
  if (!value) {
    logger.error(`Missing the environment variable '${name}'`);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

envTest(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEYS, 'TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEYS');
envTest(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET, 'TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET');
envTest(TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, 'TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY');
envTest(TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, 'TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET');
envTest(MONGO_URI, 'MONGO_URI');
envTest(DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN, 'DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN');
envTest(DISCORD_CMD_PREFIX, 'DISCORD_CMD_PREFIX');
envTest(DISCORD_BOT_OWNER_ID, 'DISCORD_BOT_OWNER_ID');
envTest(TEMP, 'TEMP');

// Ensure we can access the temp directory
try {
  fs.accessSync(process.env.TEMP, fs.constants.F_OK);
} catch (err) {
  logger.error(`Unable to access the temp directory: ${process.env.TEMP}`);
  logger.debug(err);
  process.exit(1);
}

// Ensure all the commands we need to function exist via PATH
if (!commandExistsSync('ffmpeg')) {
  logger.error('\'ffmpeg\' is not available on the command line');
  process.exit(1);
}
if (!commandExistsSync('gm')) {
  logger.error('\'gm\' is not available on the command line');
  process.exit(1);
}

// Passed all the startup tests
// Continue to load application
require('./bin');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you have installed dotenv, you didn't run it. You should have `require('dotenv').config()` at the start of your program.

Comment: Thanks. But now, 'gm' is not available on the command line - new error